# simultaneously use of php5 and php7 on Fedora 27

Tags: php, apache, fedora-27

I am trying to configure everything in order to run simultaneously php5 and php7 on Fedora 27. I am using Remi's guides from [here](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) and [here](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation), I am able to switch versions in the command line with `module load/unload php71/php56`
but on the page where I output `phpinfo();` I get php version of 7.1. I have also
running php56-php-fpm.service and php71-php-fpm.service running.
What should I check or where to search? Thank you.

php.conf file:

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php (5 or 7) is not available
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

also there are php56-php.conf and php71-php.conf files. As I understand mod_php is serving files instead of php-fpm, is there any method to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Check all **SetHandler** Directives in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*conf`

Each package comes with its configuration file (php##-php.conf), you may have to disable them to be able to set the proper version per vhost / project / directory, or ensure your configuration files are loaded **after** provided ones.

Comment: I have added a warning in linked howto.

Comment: After commenting all SetHandlers in php.conf and php71-php.conf nothing changes if you need some more information I can provide you...

Comment: It works for me with the exact configuration described in the HOWTO... hard to say without checking all the apache configuration files related to PHP.